# Custom jQuery plugin undefined inside click event in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

When adding your own custom plugin, and then trying to use that plugin inside a click event, IE (or at least IE8) says that function is undefined (the error message is "Object doesn't support this property or method). Why?

```
    $.fn.myFunc = function() {
        alert( $(this).text() );
    };
    $('p').click(function() {
        $(this).myFunc();
    });
```

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the `$(this)` variable, which it gets just fine, because you can replace it with any selected element and the problem remains that `myFunc` is undefined inside the click event function.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this code runs just fine under IE8, and the problem lied with an addon (specifically Freemake YouTube downloader). I used the Call Stack button (very useful) inside the IE Developer Tools to find what was being called after my function, and I saw functions being called from what I had previously assumed was my minified version of jQuery, but on closer inspection it was for a version I wasn't loading. Scrolling further into the file (actually not a file at all but a loaded JS block) I saw functions for a YouTube downloader that had automatically installed an IE addon (I never use IE but it may have caused other conflicts I would have noticed if I did use it), so went to disable that addon, and lo, everything worked as expected after that.

To make sure it was just a conflict with the addon itself and not with the version of jQuery they were embedding, I tried loading that version myself (1.8.3) and it worked fine.